# How do I say Laravel that if thread belongs to this user, alow him to

Tags: php, multithreading, laravel

I'm doing a blog with Laravel Framework and I allready have a Login/Register and a thread section. In my Blog you just can edit a thread if you're logged in. Now I have the problem that if I'm logged in, I can edit and delete every thread. It doesn't matter if it's my thread or if it is from another user. Well now I need something to say my laravel code that I'm just allowed to edit/dekete my own threads.

I've found this: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/authorization#defining-abilities

But I don't really understand how I implement this to my code. And do I need a in my database any reference? like this user belongs to this thread?

Well I'm kind of new in laravel.. I hope someone can help me

PS: I'm sorry for my bad english, I'm from germany.

Edit/Update/Delete function:

```
public function edit($id)
    {
        $thread = Thread::query()->findOrFail($id);
        return view('test.edit', [
            'thread' => $thread
        ]);
    }

    public function update($id, StoreRequest $request)
    {
        $thread = Thread::query()->findOrFail($id);
        $thread->fill($request->all());
        $thread->save();
        return redirect(action('Test\\TestController@show', [$thread->id]));
    }

    public function destroy($id)
    {
        $thread = Thread::query()->findOrFail($id);
        $thread->delete();
        return redirect(action("Test\\TestController@index"));
    }
```

my thread model:

```
public function user() {
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class, "name");
}
```

How I add a new thread:

If I press "add thread" I'm getting directed to my add function in my controller:

add function:

```
public function add()
    {
        return view('test.add', [
            'entries' => Thread::query()->get()
        ]);
    }
```

in my add.blade I have my formular and this formular directs me to my "store function " in my controller:

store function:

```
public function store(StoreRequest $request)
    {
        Thread::create($request->all());
        return redirect(action('Test\\TestController@index'));
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can attach the user_id to the thread so anytime you want to update or delete you check if the current logged in user bears that user_id then you do accordingly.

add **user_id** to **threads** table

Then in your save function() do this.

```
public function save(Request $request){
    $thread = new Thread;
    $thread->user_id = Auth::user()->id;
    // rest of fields goes here
    $thread->save(); 
}
```

then in your edit, update or delete function

```
public function edit($id)
{
    $thread = Thread::query()->findOrFail($id);

    // You can use laravel authorization/policies to achieve this too
    if($thread->user_id != Auth::user()->id){
       // Return to view with your custom error message telling 
       // the user he is not authorized to edit this thread 
    }

    return view('test.edit', [
        'thread' => $thread
    ]);
}

public function update($id, StoreRequest $request)
{
    $thread = Thread::query()->findOrFail($id);

    // You can use laravel authorization/policies to achieve this too
    if($thread->user_id != Auth::user()->id){
       // Return to view with your custom error message telling 
       // the user he is not authorized to edit this thread 
    }

    $thread->fill($request->all());
    $thread->save();
    return redirect(action('Test\\TestController@show', [$thread->id]));
}

public function destroy($id)
{
    $thread = Thread::query()->findOrFail($id);

    // You can use laravel authorization/policies to achieve this too
    if($thread->user_id != Auth::user()->id){
       // Return to view with your custom error message telling 
       // the user he is not authorized to delete this thread 
    }

    $thread->delete();
    return redirect(action("Test\\TestController@index"));
}
```

Comment: mhh could you tell me how I can do that in a more specific way?

Comment: I did this and it nearly worked perfect. I created a new thread as I was logged in. After I wrote a new thread I tried to update my thread and got a error message. I've got the error message cause the user_id in my thread table haven't the same id like the id in my users table.  --  And I don't really understand this save function. In the save function you wrote: // rest of fields goes here ---- Do you mean my formular to add a thread? Cause my formular is on my view. Sorry for all this, I'm still new to laravel :/

Comment: Yes please. The save function is how you add your thread. i guess you have done that already since you have the user_id in your threads table. Dont forget to vote and accept the answer if it works

Comment: I updated my question with some other functions in my controller, because I allready have something like your save method. -- My problem is now that if I save a new thread, the user_id of my threads table don't have the same number like the id of the user who's logged in :/

Comment: In your Thread Model add 'user_id' to your fillable array. List the columns/fields in your threads table for me to see.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105546/discussion-between-itzme488-and-oseintow).